# How to add a focus style to an editable ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, styling

I've been looking at the following [example](http://www.designerwpf.com/2008/02/07/the-wpf-designers-guide-to-styling-the-combobox/) on how to style the `ComboBox`, but I haven't been able to create a focus effect when going into an editable combo box. Whenever the `ComboBox` receives focus, it should go into edit mode and the component should have a focus style.

The basic problem is that whenever I go into the edit mode, it's not the surrounding `ComboBox` which actually has the focus, but the text subcomponent and I haven't been able to create a `Trigger` on the text component which modifies the `ComboBox`'s border style since I don't know how to refer to the parent component from the trigger.

I've tried adding `ControlTemplate` `Trigger` on the `TextBox`, or style trigger. I've tried to refer to the `ComboBox` by name or by using the `TemplateBinding` option, but without any luck. A simple example would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind IsKeyboardFocusWithin to IsDropDownOpen

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SortedItems}"
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
          IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: @sidneyandrews Great! This worked when eveything else I've tried has failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void cmbSpecialHandling_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thickness th = new Thickness(2);
            cmbSpecialHandling.BorderThickness = th;
            cmbSpecialHandling.BorderBrush = this.FindResource("TabFocusColor") as SolidColorBrush;
        }

        private void cmbSpecialHandling_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thickness th = new Thickness(2);
            cmbSpecialHandling.BorderThickness = th;
            cmbSpecialHandling.BorderBrush = this.FindResource("TabFocusColor") as SolidColorBrush;
        }

        private void cmbSpecialHandling_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbSpecialHandling.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the border brush of combobox in its `Gotfocus` and make it transparent in lost focus:

```
private void comboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thickness th = new Thickness(2);
        comboBox.BorderThickness = th;
        comboBox.BorderBrush = this.FindResource("TabFocusColor") as SolidColorBrush;
                  or
     comboBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
    }


    private void comboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
```