# WPF Editable Combobox IsFocused problem

Tags: wpf, combobox, focus, editmode

I am developing a Watermarked `ComboBox` by modifying the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`.  Everything is fine when the `ComboBox` is not in an editable mode, but when I change the edit mode to True, the `IsFocused` property is never set to True.  This is because in edit mode, the `ComboBox` is using a `TextBox`.  This is an exact copy of this [StackOverflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543804/how-to-add-a-focus-style-to-an-editable-combobox-in-wpf) .  There are no responses to that question.

Please drop a line if you know how to solve this, or please point me to links that provide a Watermark `ComboBox` implementation.
Thanks,
Rey.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a focus style to an editable ComboBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543804/how-to-add-a-focus-style-to-an-editable-combobox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to use the [`IsKeyboardFocused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocused.aspx) or [`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin.aspx) instead

Comment: IsKeyboardFocusWithin Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **IsFocused** or **IsKeyboardFocused** or **IsKeyboardFocusWithin** properties of the *TextBox* control which is within the *ComboBox* control. The TextBox can be found at e.OriginalSource(TextChangedEventArgs property).

It worked for me.