# Using a Style Trigger to change another control

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a ListBox and a Button on a Window.  When the ListBox has the focus, the `IsEnabled` property of the Button should be True.  Here is what I've tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter
        Property="Margin"
        Value="15,0,15,20"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
            <Setter TargetName="btnActivate" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This seems very straightforward but I get an error message that

> btnActivate is not recognized.

What is the proper way to do this?

**EDIT 1**
I implemented MoonMoo's suggested link as follows:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=lstInactive, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource cvtr}}">
```

using this converter:

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim IsFocused As Integer = CInt(value)
        Return If(IsFocused > -1, True, False)
    End Function
```

This works to turn IsEnabled on when the listbox is focused but does not turn it off when the listbox loses focus.  I think maybe I have to look into a multibinding that also binds to the other control that might get the focus.

**EDIT 2**
I should mention that I tried:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=lstInactive, Path=IsFocused, Converter={StaticResource cvtr}}">
```

with a converter:

```
Return CBool(value)
```

but that did not changed the button's IsEnabled property

Comment: Something similar has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068606/wpf-bind-a-control-visibility-to-the-focused-property-of-another-control. You could bind to the IsEnabled property instead.

Comment: @MoonMoo  See my edit to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `DataTrigger` for your button instead:

```
<Button> 
   <Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused,ElementName=YourListBoxName}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: This is very close but doesn't work.  When using IsFocused, the IsEnabled property of the button doesn't change.  So I tried Focused (which is the property named in the ListBox documentation, but got a run-time error that that property "is not found".   Also, see next comment.

Comment: So I tried all other ListBox properties that made any sense and got one to partially work.  I tried SelectedIndex with a value of 0 and that worked when I clicked on the first item in the ListBox.  So I tried the obvious next step by using a value of "> -1" which did not give a run-time error but also did not change the IsEnabled property of the button.

Comment: So you want something that if any of the item gets selected the button should get enabled?

Comment: No, not quite.  I want it to be enabled if the listbox has the focus.  I just tried using SelectedIndex as a way of testing various approaches to see if I could get what I want.