# Focus bug with RMB in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently found what I think to be a bug but maybe it is intended behaviour that I am unaware of. I am not going to bore you with what I was trying to do but it led me to testing a very simple dumbed down version and the weird interaction still occurs. To easily display this I decided to just change the foreground colour when the focus is within the combobox. If you press LMB or MMB on the combobox it works fine everytime, it turns red and back to the original foreground colour when losing focus just as expected. But when I press RMB it works once and never again. Every time after the initial focus I am unable to move focus to that combobox using MMB and RMB until the combobox is reset in some way (If its in an items control and the binded collection is updated). This is very weird behaviour and I am trying to figure out a way around it of there is a way. Here is the code for the style you can use and test yourself.

```
<Style x:Key="test" TargetType="ComboBox">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

edit: It is also worth noting this isn't exclusive to the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property, it occurs for, at the very least, IsFocused, IsKeyboardFocused, and IsKeyboardFocusWithin properties which is why I believe it has something to do with how focus is handled in someway.

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? Do you see anything in VS's XAML Binding Errors window? Have you tried source-stepping into WPF?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54217724/17034

Comment: .NET 6, no errors, have not tried source-stepping

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't really pertain to my question as I am not altering the IsEditable property and I have tried all of those focus properties as shown in my post and still this interaction occurs

Comment: Hmm, no, you haven't tried that approach yet.  You don't have to.